# how to store and retrieve items?

Tags: java, database

I need to store all encrypted messages so it may be retrieved and displayed by pressing a button, that is, press the button 3 times for the last 3rd message;

After retrieving an encrypted message , let user guess (type into a textbox) the original message and press a button. Display how many characters are correct and how many wrong.

Really sorry for the bad question. here's an example of my current coding. basically i take the input from a textfield. so how do i store and retrieve the input?

```
String input = txtInput.getText();

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
char[] charArray =  input.toCharArray(); 

for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i +=2) 
{ 
    if(i+1 < charArray.length) 
    { 
        //even 
        builder.append(charArray[i+1]); 
    } 
    //odd 
    builder.append(charArray[i]); 
} 

String flippedText = builder.toString(); 
lblencryted.setText(flippedText); 

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){ 
    String[] storeArray = {flippedText};     
} 

}                                         

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     {                                          
String input = txtInput.getText(); 

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
char[] charArray =  input.toCharArray(); 

for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i +=2) 
{ 
    if(i+1 < charArray.length) 
    { 
        //even 
        builder.append(charArray[i+1]); 
    } 
    //odd 
    builder.append(charArray[i]); 
} 

String flippedText = builder.toString(); 
lblretrieve.setText(flippedText);  
}                                         

public static void main(String args[]) { 
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            new Encryption().setVisible(true); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Is your Caps Lock key broken?

Comment: Don't.......shout. You already got the input and want to store it permanently or do you want to know how to get the input from the input field? *store* is ambiguous here.

Comment: my bad.. didn't realised it was on. i managed to get the input but i'm unsure how to store it.

Comment: @ProgrammingNub: And where do you want to store it? Database, text file, etc ?

Comment: store it in a class called storage.

Comment: does that make and sense? which is easiest to extract from?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [JDBC api](http://java.sun.com/products/jdbc/overview.html).

If your texts are short than I would recommend [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) go see how much matches there are.

Comment: ah i don't quite get what's there. 
i'm not very good at this.